# How to plot from groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `DataFrame` that I am analyzing using `groupby()` function. And I want to plot the result.

This is the piece of code:

```
df = df[(df['Type'] == 'u')]
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month 
mean_prices = df.groupby((['Suburb','Rooms', 'Month']))['Price'].agg(np.mean).round()
mean_prices
```

the results are looking like:

```
Suburb              Rooms  Month
    Abbotsford          1      5         432250.0
                               7         470000.0
                               8         441500.0
                               10        300000.0
                               11        490000.0
                               12        481000.0
                        2      5         970000.0
                               6         500000.0
                               10        542000.0
                               11        725000.0
                               12        760000.0
    Aberfeldie          1      12        380000.0
                        2      5         456000.0
                               11        373000.0
                        3      9         726000.0
                               12        845000.0
    Airport West        2      7         468250.0
```

I want to ad to `agg()` `np.max` and `np.min` and make a boxplot for each 'Suburb' value that should show the max the min and the mean values for each suburb. How to do this?

Comment: It looks like you're misunderstanding what 'groupby' actually does. I'm mildly shocked that the 4th line doesn't raise an error.

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny it is a data set from Kaggle

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/anthonypino/melbourne-housing-market

Comment: You could also use `factorplot` functionality from the `seaborn` package to draw one boxplot for each Suburb value

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate to apply multiple functions like this:

```
mean_prices = df.groupby((['Suburb','Rooms', 'Month']))['Price'].aggregate({'Mean': np.mean, 'Min': np.min, 'Max': np.max}).round().reset_index()
mean_prices.head()
```

You get:

```
    Suburb    Rooms Month   Mean    Min         Max
0   Abbotsford  1   5   432250.0    423500.0    441000.0
1   Abbotsford  1   7   470000.0    470000.0    470000.0
2   Abbotsford  1   8   441500.0    426000.0    457000.0
3   Abbotsford  1   10  300000.0    300000.0    300000.0
4   Abbotsford  1   11  490000.0    480000.0    500000.0
```